# DLL's only partially loaded

Tags: memory-management, dll, citrix

My application contains some specific logic regarding DLL's (a bit too complex to explain here).
But in that logic I noticed the following (on a customer's Citrix terminal server):

When calling GetModuleInformation on the NTDLL.DLL, the returned MODULEINFO returns a first address (lpBaseOfDll) of 0x7d600000 and a size of 0xf0000 (so its last byte should be at 0x7d6effff).

However, in a crash dump file I see the following in WinDbg (using !address):

```
* 7d600000 7d601000     1000   Image "J:\WINDOWS\system32\ntdll.dll"
* 7d610000 7d65f000    4f000   <unclassified> 
* 7d65f000 7d660000     1000   <unclassified> 
* 7d660000 7d699000    39000   <unclassified> 
* 7d6a0000 7d6a6000     6000   <unclassified> 
* 7d6b0000 7d6df000    2f000   <unclassified> 
* 7d6e0000 7d6e4000     4000   <unclassified> 
* 7d800000 7d801000     1000   Image "J:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\gdi32.dll"
* 7d810000 7d855000    45000   <unclassified> 
* 7d860000 7d861000     1000   <unclassified> 
* 7d861000 7d862000     1000   <unclassified> 
* 7d870000 7d871000     1000   <unclassified> 
* 7d880000 7d882000     2000   <unclassified>
```

So it looks like the NTDLL.DLL only has a size of 0x1000 instead of 0xf0000.

That explains why calls to VirtualLock beyond the size of 0x1000 fail (error code 998: Invalid access to memory location) and accessing the memory crashes the application.

Where can I find an explanation why the DLL's are only partially loaded?  Does Citrix replace the DLL's by stubs but doesn't correctly report this through GetModuleInformation?  Or is something else going on?

And why is the NTDLL.DLL loaded from J:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32, while most of the other DLL's are loaded from J:\WINDOWS\SYSWOW64? (this could indicate that indeed some 32/64-stub is used).

It's the first time I encounter this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Citrix doesn't stub out DLLs, but it does do a lot of hooking of various DLLs. That would be my best guess for the issues you are seeing. The following articles describe hooking and how you can disable it:

http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX107824

http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX107825

Try disabling hooking for your application to see if these issues go away.